# mySQL- combining two tables with one same column value and compare start date and end date

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I am trying to combine two tables that has same column value which is t1.Bid
and t2.id then when they are combine I wanted to display all the address that status=Active ,address is the same with the address of Bid =  2001 and has conflict in the startdate and enddate range of Bid = "2001". I think theres a problem in my query I am beginner so any advice will be really appreciated thank you.

tblAddress:

```
id (VARCHAR(255))           
Address (LONGTEXT)   
startdate (LONGTEXT)   
enddate   (LONGTEXT) 
Bid   (LONGTEXT)
```

tblbook:

```
id (VARCHAR(255))           
STATUS (LONGTEXT)   


tblAddress

id      Address        startdate      enddate                 Bid
x12es1  Place1       2018-08-27       2018-08-30               2001
x12fs2  Place1       2018-08-28       2018-08-30               2002
x1sd13  Place1       2018-08-27       2018-09-29              2003 
x12f14  Place4       2018-09-17       2018-09-18               2004


tblbook

id        Status
2001      Active
2002      Active
2003      Active
2004      Active

My output doesnt display anything

Bid         id           Status            startdate        enddate     Address

Desired Output
will only display those who has a conflict with bid 2001 start date and endate

Bid           id            Status                      startdate                enddate          Address
2002          2002            Active                      2018-08-28          2018-08-30         Place1
2003          2003            Active                      2018-08-27           2018-09-29        Place1    

Query

SELECT t2.Bid,t1.id,t1.Status,t2.startdate,t2.endddate,t2.Address
 FROM tblbook t1  INNER JOIN  tblAddress t2
ON t1.id =t2.Bid
WHEREt1.Status = 'Active' AND   
@check_period_start BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d')AND STR_TO_DATE(t2.enddate,'%Y-%m-%d') 
  AND @check_period_end BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d')AND STR_TO_DATE(t2.enddate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: what is the value of check_period_start & check_period_end variable

Comment: Could you please add table structure and insert queries ?

Comment: its a longtext startdate and enddate of tblAddress

Comment: Could you please explain **longtext** ? or add that longtext in your question

Comment: What does conflict look like?

Comment: My startdate and enddate is longtext I am converting them to date I dont really know if I am doing it right I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tblAddress t
where exists(select 1 from tblbook
             where id = t.bid and status = 'Active')
and exists(select 1 from tblAddress
           where bid = 2001 and
           t.startdate < enddate and
           t.enddate > startdate)
and bid <> 2001
```

You need to have correct datatype in your dates columns! I mean, it should be `date`.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tHn8zMpLrs71fNSgspkSih/0)

Comment: no error but not displaying anything not displaying desired output thank you verymuch for help really appreciate

Comment: Thank you very much I will try

Comment: It is working you are really a great help I convert my longtext  using STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d') then try your code it works but I dont really know how it happened you  are great! Can you tell me how? Thank you

Comment: @Wonderer If it works, you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote. If you want to know how it happened, you should read about `EXISTS` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should build a proper date also for @check_period_start and @check_period_end

```
SELECT t2.Bid,t1.id,t1.Status,t2.startdate,t2.endddate,t2.Address
FROM tblbook t1  
INNER JOIN  tblAddress t2 ON t1.id =t2.Bid
WHEREt1.Status = 'Active' 
AND str_to_date(@check_period_start, '%Y-%m-%d') 
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d')
            AND STR_TO_DATE(t2.enddate,'%Y-%m-%d') 
AND str_to_date(@check_period_end,, '%Y-%m-%d')  
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d')
            AND STR_TO_DATE(t2.enddate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line AND STR_TO_DATE(@check_period_start, '%Y-%m-%d') when I tried to put the code 
You have an error IN your SQL syntax; CHECK the manual that corresponds TO your MySQL SERVER VERSION FOR the RIGHT syntax TO USE near ' '%Y-%m-%d')  
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(t2.startdate,'%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @Wonderer remove 1 comma from **@check_period_end,, '%Y-%m-%d'**

Comment: no error but not displaying anything not displaying desired output thank you verymuch for help really appreciate